# How to send "Windows" key to VNC session from Mac keyboard

Tags: macos, vnc

I'm controlling a Windows computer from my Mac via a VNC session, but cannot use my normal commands because the Apple/Command key is not mapping to the "Windows" key. However, when I control a PC via RDP from my Mac, this works. I found this link, but it's not helping: https://www.realvnc.com/docs/mac-keyboard-mapping.html

EDIT: Just opened the on-screen keyboard in Windows, and the apple/command key is mapping to ALT instead of the Windows key.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect the answer could depend on what VNC client software you are using.  (If you don't get an answer here, try another Stack Exchange site, such as [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks, TOOGAM. I'm using RealVNC, but also tried native VNC in OS X and it's the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RealVNC documentation for [Keyboard mapping to and from a Mac](https://www.realvnc.com/docs/mac-keyboard-mapping.html) (the page you found) says that the left command key (CmdL) on the Mac keyboard is mapped to the left Alt key (AltL) on a PC. This is the mapping you found.

The documentation also says the right command key (CmdR) on the Mac keyboard is mapped to the left Windows key (WinL). Have you tried CmdR?

Note that:

> AltR and WinR can only be produced by changing the [VNC parameters](https://www.realvnc.com/docs/mac-keyboard-mapping.html#mac-keyboard-mapping-parameters) from
>   their defaults.

Comment: Thanks very much, creidhne! This is answered my question!

Comment: ...I'm just so used to using the CmdR key on my Mac keyboard to pass the Windows key into RDP sessions that I never even thought to try the CmdL key! Always helps to "RTFM" (read the fantastic manual). ;)